# Backwards Compatibility for Angular UI Bootstrap 0.14.0

Tags: angular-ui-bootstrap

Did PR #4514 make it into the 0.14.0 tag? Right now 0.14.0 isn't backwards compatible with 0.13.x when I recently re-built a project.

```
DropdownController is now deprecated. Use UibDropdownController instead.
vendor.min.js:15dropdown-toggle is now deprecated. Use uib-dropdown-toggle instead.
vendor.min.js:15dropdown-menu is now deprecated. Use uib-dropdown-menu instead.
vendor.min.js:15dropdown is now deprecated. Use uib-dropdown instead.
```

Answer (score 3):

It should be 100% backward compatible. It only prompts you to update all your directives to use the new prefix.

There are some issues as today (with angular 1.3.x), but we will try to make a hot fix release ASAP.

Comment: Looks like this was not the case until 0.14.1 was tagged with the full backward compatibility.

Comment: I'm having the same issue. "dropdown-menu is now deprecated. Use uib-dropdown-menu instead." The only place being referenced by angular is in the ui-bootstrap-tpls-0.14.3.min.js